# Is there a list of RPG jargon words?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, terminology

*Though I'm also interested in general slang words, I'm more specifically asking for slang used in **D&D 3.5e**.*

While looking at the comments of a question, I saw someone introducing BAB as abbreviation for Base Attack Bonus to the person asking the question. Though I'm familiar with some of the most common jargon, like the standard STR CON DEX INT WIS CHA, I would like to know what other jargon terms are used.

**Is there a list somewhere with common and somewhat uncommon jargon in (tabletop) RPGs, specifically for D&D?**

Comment: Are you looking for a technical glossary of abbreviations, or are you looking for gamer jargon/slang?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list. We don't tend to handle lists well as a site, so you'd probably be better off asking this in a forum.

Comment: @Dakeyras Not so: it's off-topic to ask a question that would result in us *creating* a list of answers. Asking for an resource elsewhere is OK, even if that resource happens to be a list. In actual fact, this is a duplicate of an existing open question.